# CSS in Visual Studio Code - Select multiple lines and comment each line within selection separately

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, comments

Working on CSS in Visual Studio Code I want to select multiple lines of property:value code and comment them out separately. For example

Before:

```
body {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
color: red;
}
```

After highlighting the width, height and color lines and applying auto comment with Ctrl+/, VS Code's default behaviour is to include all lines as one comment:

```
body {
/* width: 0px;
height: 0px;
color: red; */
}
```

I want to have:

```
body {
/* width: 0px; */
/* height: 0px; */
/* color: red; */
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

[image]

You hold `alt` and place the cursor on multiple lines and `CTRL+C` to comment..

Comment: That's the best method so far, thanks. I would however prefer to be able to highlight a long block of code in one pass and use a hot key (similar to Ctrl + /) to do it though - as opposed to having to individually select each line with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down Alt and select rows/multiple lines to comment and press ‘Alt+Shift+A’. This will Block comment the selected sections. You can comment just parts of code using this method.